# Find $N$ independent solutions through Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

The Laplace Transform method gives us one solution of an Ordinary Differential Equation.
How can we use the same procedure to get $N$ independent solutions, being $N$ the order of the ODE? 
Where can I find a proof of this procedure?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What made you to think that you could use L.T. for such that OE?

Comment: Try to solve the simple ode $y''- y=0$ using L.T technique and see how many solutions you get!

Comment: @BabakS. Because it's done in fractional differential equations which are a generalization of ODE's.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal My problem is not a particular case. I'm searching for a general theorem+proof.

Comment: I understand this. But, who said that L.T technique does not give all the $n$ linearly independent solutions?

Comment: Well. When you do the inverse of the Laplace Transform you may get the general solution. But this does not mean you know how to 'split' this expression in an independent set of solutions. Am I saying something wrong?